# Difference between javascript:fnName() and normalfnname()

Tags: javascript

Can someone please explain the difference between:

```
onclick="javascript:fnName(this);"
```

...and...

```
onclick="fnName(this);"
```

Is there any performance hit? or when to use what?

Comment: Use neither, instead bind events in your Javascript (usually with jQuery these days: `$('.my-element').on('click', fnName)`

Answer (score 0):

Not actually, and usually you don't write the first one. Because `onclick` handler is handled by the JavaScript, so calling JavaScript to handle it won't be a good bet.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of event attributes it's completely useless. It's mainly used inside of the `href` attribute and allows you to create a pseudo-onclick event:

```
<a href="javascript:alert('hello')">click me</a>
```

Also you can just put it in the location input in your browser and run scripts. It's simillar to the console input.

Edit: I realized it's not really useless but it has completely different usage than you would thought. In the context of these event attributes it behaves like in a normal code and so it's a label. Try this:

```
<div onclick="javascript:while(true){while(true){alert('hello');break javascript;}}">click me</div>
```